# Using HAVING to find when exactly one row meets a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, self-join, having

If I want to find a book title that has been published in exactly two different years, does this work?

```
SELECT books1.title
FROM Books books1 INNER JOIN Books books2 ON books1.title = books2.title
WHERE books1.year <> books2.year
GROUP BY books1.title
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

So I think that would join all the rows to the other rows with the same title, and then it would return the titles where one and ONLY one row has a different books1.year and books2.year for the same title. Is that what it does?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  Did it return an error?

Answer (score 4):

you can group the records by `title` and count and filter only who has two unique values of `year`.

```
SELECT title
FROM Books 
GROUP BY title
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) = 2
```

Comment: Oh that's much simpler why didn't I just think of that? >.< I will choose this answer when the timer lets me.